# Using jQuery to animate a vairable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-animate

Is there a way to animate a variable using `jQuery.animate()`? I'm looking for the simplest way of doing something like this:

```
$element.animate({
    whatever: 100
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function( now, fx ){
      // do something useful here using the value of "now"
    }
  });
```

but without using `$element` or any of its properties, I just want to setup the animation using `from`, `to`, `duration` and `easing function` and then be able to call my custom logic using the `now` value supplied to `step` (from and to will be integers).

Obviously this works:

```
$("#draggable").animate({ test: 1000 }, {
                duration: 5000,
                easing: "swing",
                step: function (a, b) {
                    console.error(a);
                    //$(this).after("<div>Animation complete.</div>");
                }
            });
```

but id' nice to get it working with no element referenced.

Comment: No you can't. jQuery animate needs a target element. However, you may use requestanimationframe (if you're not worried by IE9<).

Comment: Thanks for that but will i have to implement easings and acceleration logic myself then?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. Here is a good list of them: https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294 
You can integrate them as a service, so you can call it from your controller.

The only thing I miss from that library are bouncing effects though